# PHP cookies and sessions problem

Tags: php, cookies, session

How can I do one login script that uses cookies for login and for example I want to check if the visitor is logged in without querying the database.

For example I want on frontpage to show some menu's only for logged in users .

so I must do if(isLoggedIn()) show the menu . But that's a query everytime the page loads so it's not very good

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is your login set up? Are they assigned a `SESSION` variable when they log onto the website? With more information, we can provide a better answer.

Comment: You have to be careful to get a solution that is robust to session forgery (that is someone "stealing" somebody else's session, or creating one that looks genuine when looked at by your PHP). That's usually not as easy as one initially thinks.

Comment: Ideally I want to make one cookie with login and password, so I can make it last as much as I need. But How do I check if he's logged in without doing a query to the mysql to check if the password or username is valid? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
session_start();

// Use $HTTP_SESSION_VARS with PHP 4.0.6 or less
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
  $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;

  // Add all the relevant user information data
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
  $_SESSION['etc'] = $etc;
}
```

Then you can request the user data to the $_SESSION global array.
E.g.: requesting if the user is loggedIn (Don't forget to call to session_start() first):

```
function isLoggedIn() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn']);
}
```

If you want to log out:

```
session_destroy();
```

The timeout can be handled in the php.ini file:

```
; After this number of seconds, stored data will be seen as 'garbage' and
; cleaned up by the garbage collection process.
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
```

Or you can handle ini variables in run time using ini_set:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $sessionMaxLifeTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can the funcion [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) to create a cookie and use this function to check if the cookie `loggedIn` is set and not false. :)

```
function isLoggedIn() {
    return (isset($_COOKIE['loggedIn']) && $_COOKIE['loggedIn']);
}
```

Comment: yes but it can easily be modified and hacked by any user. If I'll do that, I can easily set it to true and modify the username to admin, add one random password and I will be logged in as admin :\

Answer (score 0):

you can use sessions in php for this. Add session_start(); to your pages, after login, maybe againstan database set an flag in the session.

```
// user logged in sucessful
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
```

Than check on your pages:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] === true) {
 // display menu item
}
```

Comment: yes, I thinked about this, but if I add this, it will expire in 20 minutes. The cookies for username and password will last for 3 hours for example so I will have the username and the password but not the loggedin cookie

Answer (score 0):

Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php instantly after logging in to set a flag, then use $_COOKIES to check for this flag. Alternatively you can set this flag to $_SESSION and then check it there.

Comment: But cookies can be easily modified

Answer (score 0):

PHP's $_SESSION is file-based, so no DB hit if you're using that (though DBs are almost always faster than file lookups, so that may not be all that helpful).

You can use an in-memory cache like memcached.

Or, for a little less security, you could store a second cookie with a time and hash.  When you issue it, you concatenate the present time and a secret salt that only your application logic knows, then md5() or sha1() it.  Every browse, you just check that the time in the cookie is within the last hour (or whatever time period you configure) and that the hash is valid.  It can be spoofed for an hour, and you'll need to check legit sessions some other way, but it might be enough for just menu-based stuff.